# How to set coordinates for KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means

I'm using the OpenCV algorithm kmeans for clustering. For the first round I want to choose k1 and k2 locations, I don't want them to be set randomly. Therefore I use `KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS`:

```
kmeans(points, K, labels, TermCriteria, attempts, KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS, centers)
```

But how do you set coordinates for `KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS`?

Comment: That flag is used to set initial **labels**, not centers. Setting initial centers won't be trivial. However, if you already know the centers, why do you need to use kmeans at all?

Answer (score -2):

as explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html) the coordinates are simple arrays with the coordinates of the pixels in your input and what labels you want to set them at the beining.